# feeding tensorflow sparse matrix for sparse-dense-multiplication. Getting the following error: TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use `tensorflow tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(X, W1)`. 
X is defined as tf.placeholder:

`X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, size])`.

W is tf.Variable

While feeding into the dict, I am passing in tensorflow sparse matrix. But I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.

How do I let the *sparse_tensor_dense_matmul* module know that I will be passing in sparse tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a SparseTensor through the placeholder, you can use [sparse_placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders#sparse_placeholder):

```
sparse_place = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float64)
mul_result = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(sparse_place, some_dense_tensor)
```

You can use it as follows:

```
dense_version = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_place)
sess.run(dense_version, feed_dict={sparse_place: tf.SparseTensorValue([[0,1], [2,2]], [1.5, 2.9], [3, 3])})
Out: array([[ 0. ,  1.5,  0. ],
            [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
            [ 0. ,  0. ,  2.9]])
```

Alternatively, you can create three separate placeholders for values, shape and indices, e.g.:

```
indices = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
values = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)
sparse_tensor = tf.SparseTensor(indices, shape, values)
sess.run(sparse_tensor, feed_dict={shape: [3, 3], indices: [[0,1], [2,2]], values: [1.5, 2.9]})
```

Comment: I found another way to do the same. The placeholder, itself can be sparse placeholder.   X = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float64).